# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'

Tags: python, gis

I ran @Borealis code (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411468/calculate-ndvi-using-python ) on Ubuntu Mate and although I have installed arcgis with this command: `pip3 install arcgis`,
I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow_code.py", line 3, in <module>
    import arcpy, string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'
```

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?? because I cannot find a reliable solution in google search, most of the answers are related to Windows/anaconda...

Comment: Hint ... https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/what-is-arcpy-.htm

Comment: Thanks but I use python code on Ubuntu Mate. The above code is related to anaconda, which I do not use.